# SQL : Retriving the primary from one table twice for different rows

Tags: sql, self-join

I have 2 tables:

Table 1: TeamParticipant

```
Primary Key(Id)
Name 
Country
```

Example of TeamParticipant table

```
23,Brazil,Brazil
25,England,England
```

Table 2: Matches

```
Primary Key: Id
EventId
Foreign Key: TeamParticipantId1// Primary Key of table TeamParticipant
Foreign Key2: TeamParicipantId2//Primary Key of table TeamParticipant
```

Example of Matches table

```
1,1,23,25
```

I need to merge the tables and produce the following ouput

```
Id,EventId, Country1(TeamParticipantId1), Country2(TeamParticipantId2)
```

example of output I need to generate:

```
1,1,Brazil, England
```

I am stuck the sql logic using joins
please advise

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the table `TeamParticipant` twice with different alias names.

Try this:

```
SELECT M.id,M.eventid, T1.Country as Country1,T2.Country as Country2
FROM Matches M JOIN
     TeamParticipant T1 ON M.TeamParticipantId1=T1.id JOIN
     TeamParticipant T2 ON M.TeamParticipantId2=T2.id
```

Result:

```
ID  EVENTID  COUNTRY1   COUNTRY2
1   1        Brazil     England
```

See the result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff8f5/1).

**Explanation:**

Here table `TeamParticipant` is joined twice with the table `Matches` with different alias names `T1` and `T2` on `TeamParticipantId1` and `TeamParticipantId2` respectively.